Different errors when loading Metal library in Python (Segmentation Fault, Bus Error, Killed, ...)
I am trying to use a Metal shader in Python. As I am stuck with loading the library, I wrote a really simple example:
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void helloWorldKernel(device uint *output [[ buffer(0) ]],
                              uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    // Assign a constant value to the output buffer
    output[id] = 42; // This sets the value at index id to 42
}

Compiled it with (note the fcikernel flag, which seems to be required, in XCode I would otherwise get "symbols not found for target: air64-apple-ios12.0.0' after update xcode to xcode 12"
xcrun -sdk macosx metal -fcikernel -c test.metal -o test.air
xcrun -sdk macosx metallib test.air -o test.metallib

This is how I try to load the library into my Python class:
def init(self):
# Create a Metal device
self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
if self.device is None:
raise Exception("Metal is not supported on this device.")
# Load the Metal library from the metallib file
metallib_path = "test.metallib"  # Ensure this path is correct
try:
    with open(metallib_path, "rb") as f:
        metallib_data = f.read()
except IOError as e:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to read the Metal library file: {e}")
            

print('Load the Metal library')
# Load the Metal library
error = objc.nil  # We need to capture the error if it occurs
self.library, error = self.device.newLibraryWithData_error_(metallib_data, objc.nil)
if self.library is None:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to load Metal library. Error: {error}")

Now I run the Python script with:
python test.py -framework Metal

I get several error messages after "Load the Metal library", I run the above line several times, I sometimes get different messages, always one of those:

Killed: 9
Segmentation fault: 11
Bus error: 10

But at some point, I get this one:

Exception: Failed to load Metal library. Error: Error
Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid library file (unexpected
end of file)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid library file
(unexpected end of file)}

The library is there, it's not empty, I don't get compiler errors. And it seems like I somehow have a memory problem here. But I am totally stuck.
//UPDATE
Worth to mention: I tried referring to the Metal file itself, like this good starting point:
https://gist.github.com/alvinwan/f7bb0cdd26c018f40052f9944fc5c679
It's using newLibraryWithSource_options_error_ instead of newLibraryWithData_error_. Which will load the source file but eventually stops with this error:

error: symbol(s) not found for target 'air64-apple-macosx14.6.0'

Which is the same when I compile it in XCode without and adjustments to the build setup. I have to add the -fcikernel flag, then the source will be compiled to the end.
